# change 'non-selected' li's visibility based on selection in a scrollingwindow

Tags: jquery, css, opacity, scrollto

We are currently working on a project that ties together `mapbox` implementation as well as pulling information from a database.  Currently the page has a map on the left, with markers corresponding to locations that are located in a div to it's right.

This div is a fixed width and generates li's in the ul based on however many variables correspond with the map selection (e.g. user picks 'New York', page populates New York map with 10 markers from a json file, DIV on the right pulls 10 database entries and created 10 li's in the scrolling window.

The powers that be want it so that if a user clicks on a map marker the scrolling box will automatically scroll the proper location based on the alphabetical listing that it takes place in the UL, so that the selected marker's information is visible on the right.

The question/issue we are having...is there a way that we can set a variable using jquery that we can change the opacity of the OTHER li's that are created, but are not selected?

So if you choose 'bob's burgers' from the map, it scrolls into view AND every other option that is generated in that listing has it's CSS opacity lowered?

Right now, this is the jQuery we are `jquery.scrollTo` in this call:

```
$('#scrollingwindow').scrollTo(itemname, 800, {easing: 'swing', offset:-10});
```

We're having a difficult time figuring out how to establish a variable to define the other items (NOT `itemname`) that generate in the list.

Comment: Show relevant HTML/JavaScript code

Comment: Did you try `itemname.siblings()`?

Comment: `itemname.siblings().css("opacity", 0.5)`